# spin flip with zeeman spitting via direct EM interaction

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-spin, quantization

Consider a system with [edit:] **single** electron at a deep orbital (that is, far seperated from other levels), with Zeeman splitting (in presence of constant magnetic field, of course).

**Can the system "flip" the spin by absorption / emission of a photon by *direct* interaction with the (quantized) EM field?**

My guess is no, because the two states have the same parity (=to my best knowledge, may be wrong), and since the photon has negative parity - single photon emission / absorption between these levels is not parity preserving process. (Short literature survey found spin-flips only via more complicated spin-orbit interaction)

Comment: Alexander What is a system with single electron at a deep orbital, with Zeeman splitting? An atom with one excited electron? A lot of such atoms? What is a quantized EM field?

Comment: You're right, the specifics of the problem should be ~ hydrogen like atom. The important part is the question if direct interaction can cause spin flip within the "same" separated level. Here is a basic answer to your last question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field

Comment: Although I use Wikipedia I can't agree with the definition of an EM **field**. What we can observe are electric fields, magnetic fields and EM radiation. Any force field reacts on another field of the same kind and this second field react in the same way on the first field, actio = reactio. eM radiation can act with its light pressure on other bodies or in detail photons can excite electrons, but this is not the interaction of a field.